# Diesel engine won't start when hot

Tags: ford, starting, troubleshooting, diesel, hot-start

My Ford forgo 2012 diesel refuses to start after driving long distances, but it usually starts well when it is cold. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does it start eventually or do you have to wait until its cold? Is there smoke when it finally starts?

Answer (score 2):

Probably an engine temperature sensor. I had a similar issue with a '89 VW Fox.
Cold temp would start fine and the moment it got warm.....died. Wait 10 minutes good to go until it got warm.

Good thing I had a service manual in the car and a calculator. I was near a Radio Shack and picked up 2 thermistors  put them together plugged them in and tie wrapped it the engine block. Drove to the mechanic who replaced the sensor. BTW I impressed the mechanic...never seen that done before.

The sensor had something to with the injection system.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you have injector(s) leaking down when hot.

If not that it can be a fuel pump or fuel pump pressure control, newer diesels can be complicated to diagnose here due to computer controls.